# How to use Azure Key Vault Provider with Always Encrypted Columns in Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, sqlclient, always-encrypted

I've created a boilerplate Function App in Visual Studio which, obviously works out of the gate, however, upon adding the NuGet Package dependency 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider' and building/running the HTTP trigger Function app, I get the following console error:

[image: Error_1]

> "A host error has occurred during startup operation'.
> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=''. The system cannot find the file
> specified."

After a while of researching, it appears a simple fix to this was to add the following into my .csproj:

```
<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> true </_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
```

Although, now I'm getting the following error which I'm unable to overcome:

[image]

I could be mistaken, but it appears from my research that .NetCore 3.1 (Azure Function Apps) doesn't play well with AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please refer this the same problem has been discussed here also and there is workaround for that as well : https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/744

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Rahul. That unnecessary work around is slightly outdated being from 2018. I was, however, able to find the solution which was simply to downgrade the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider package. I initially thought it was a dependency package to this one which was causing the problem, but it was the provider package (version 3.0) which was causing the issues due to NetCore 5 requirements (I'm developing in 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

**The solution** was downgrading *Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider* from 3.0 to 2.0 by uninstalling the NuGet package and reinstalling version 2.0 from the package manager in Visual Studio.

I believe the explanation is AzureKeyVault 3.0 relies on certain packages from Net Core 5.0 such as Microsoft.Extensions.Memory.Cache (if I'm recalling correctly) and I'm currently using NetCore 3.1 to develop this Azure Function App.